# is it possible to put another file at the place of default.ctp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to cakephp And I got to know **default.ctp**

*C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\src\Template\Layout\default.ctp* has the layout of the header and footer.

So I wanted to ask is it possible, I can create different layout for my different projects. If I change header footer in **default.ctp**, it will change in all the projects.

Comment: Which version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible. Create a new layout (`.ctp` file) in `/app/View/Layouts` (**Cake 2**) / `src/Template/Layout` (**Cake 3**). Let `custom.ctp`.

And in controller set the `$layout` -

```
$this->layout = 'custom';
```

[Layouts - Cake 2](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts)

[Layouts - Cake 3](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#layouts)

Comment: but the path was different becuase i am using 3.0.8